# R dataframe filling named columns with random sample data

Tags: r, dataframe, random, multiple-columns, test-data

I am trying to generate a lot of test data for other programs.
Working in R Studio I import an SPSS sav file which has 73 variables and the values and labels recorded in it using Haven as a dataframe "td". This gives me all the variable names which I need to work with. Then I delete all the existing data.

`td <- td[0,]`

Then I generate 10,000 test data rows by loading the index IDs

`td$ID <- 12340000:12349999`

So far so good.

I have a constant called `ThismanyRows <- 10000`
I have a large list of Column header names in a variable called `BinaryVariables`
And a vector of valid values for it called  `CheckedOrNot <- c(NA, 1)`

This is where the problem is:

`td[,BinaryVariables] <- sample(x = CheckedOrNot, size= ThismanyRows, replace = TRUE)`

does fill all the columns with data. But its all exactly the same data, which isn't what I want.
I want the sample function to run against each column, but not each value in each column as in.

Even when

`Fillbinary <- function () {sample(x = CheckedOrNot, size= ThismanyRows, replace = TRUE)}`

and

`td <- lapply(td[,BinaryVariables],Fillbinary)`
generates: **Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (X[[i]])**

So far I have not been able to work out how to deal with each column as a column and apply the sample function to it.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You are generating 10 values and feeding that in to replace 3 * 10 values. Adjust your sample to `size=ThismanyRows*length(BinaryVariables)`

Answer (score 1):

Let's generate some fake data first for the example:

```
BinaryVariables <- c("v1","v2","v3")
CheckedOrNot <- c(NA, 1)
ThismanyRows <- 10

td <- data.frame(ID=1:10)
```

The issue is that you are generating 10 values and feeding that in to replace 3 * 10 values.

There's a couple of ways to solve this. You might initially think, well, I'll generate 10 values 3 times, like so:

```
td[BinaryVariables] <-  replicate(length(BinaryVariables),
                          sample(x = CheckedOrNot, size=ThismanyRows, replace=TRUE),
                        simplify=FALSE)
```

That will work fine, but why `sample` 3 times if you can `sample` once and fill once?

```
td[BinaryVariables] <- sample(x = CheckedOrNot, 
                              size=ThismanyRows*length(BinaryVariables), replace = TRUE)
```

And the (well, a) result shows that the values in each column are different:

```
#   TD v1 v2 v3
#1   1 NA  1  1
#2   2 NA  1  1
#3   3 NA  1 NA
#4   4 NA  1 NA
#5   5  1 NA  1
#6   6 NA  1  1
#7   7  1 NA  1
#8   8  1  1 NA
#9   9  1 NA NA
#10 10  1 NA NA
```

Comment: @PeterKing - why would you want to loop over column names to apply a function that doesn't use the column names (hence the error that you have an unused argument)? I think you want something like `replicate(length(BinaryVariables), Fillbinary(), simplify=FALSE)`

Comment: @PeterKing - your question can be reframed as - how do I replicate the results of a function `n` column times to replace `n` columns? I mean, you could do exactly what you ask and `lapply(BinaryVariables, function(x) sample(CheckedOrNot, size= ThismanyRows, replace = TRUE))`, defining a function where the `x` argument never gets used, but that's just confusing.

Comment: Just to note: td[BinaryVariables] <- sample(x = CheckedOrNot, size= ThismanyRows*length(td), replace = TRUE)
Returned
Error: Assigned data `sample(x = CheckedOrNot, size = ThismanyRows * length(td), replace = TRUE)` must be compatible with existing data. x Existing data has 10000 rows. x Assigned data has 730000 rows. i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: The lapply solution works without error, as does the replicate version
Happy to accept either in body of answer as solution though I think the lapply version is closer to what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you working with a tibble or a plain old data.frame? I suspect a tibble since it's returning tidyverse (rlang) errors.

Comment: My library calls are expss, openxlsx, magrittr and dplyr so perhaps its been coerced into a tibble somewhere without me doing so explicitly. Not a huge fan of tibbles.

Comment: You also used `ThismanyRows * length(td)` instead of `ThismanyRows  * length(BinaryVariables)`

Comment: Just copied your code and ran it again. Get the same error, I'm afraid.

Comment: @PeterKing - I've just tried in R4.1 and and R3.6 in totally fresh sessions in both Windows and Linux and it worked each time.